# Can't connect to mongo with mongoose but can on command line?

Tags: mongodb, networking, mongoose

I have a box with a node/express webserver and box running mongo. I'm trying to get them to connect over private network instead of 0.0.0.0. They can ping each other on their private IPs. My `/etc/mongod.conf` has:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,10.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

When I ssh to my webserver box, I can successfully connect to the database so I believe my mongo configuration and firewall are setup correctly. From the command line I'm using this (and putting password when it prompts):

```
mongo mongodb://[myUser]@[10.xxx.xxx.xxx]:27017/[myDbName]?authSource=admin
```

In my express server, I am connecting like this:

```js
  const mongoUrl = `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_HOST}:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}/${process.env.MONGO_DBNAME}?authSource=admin`;
  let opts = {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  };
  if (process.env.MONGO_PASS) {
    Object.assign(opts, {
      auth: {
        user: process.env.MONGO_USER,
        password: process.env.MONGO_PASS
      },
    });
  }
  logger.info("Attempting to connect to db:", { mongoUrl });
  mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, opts, handleConnectionErr);
```

When I run this on the webserver providing the same variable values as for the other command, I get this error:

```
error: Error connecting to database: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [10.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect EHOSTUNREACH 10.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017]
```

What am I missing?

Edits:

- Nothing at all logs to my mongo server's `/var/logs/mongodb/mongod.log`
  during the connect request
- I have tried other combinations of `mongoose.connect` using just a url, just options object, or combination of both. No improvement
- I actually have another node app on a third server that connects to the same db and is doing so successfully using the nodejs mongodb
  driver - so I suspect this is either something to do with my box set
  up, or with mongoose

Comment: try to move "authSource" from url to options https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/MongoClient.html#.connect  Is there anything interesting in the mongod log on the db side?

Comment: @AlexBlex tailed the mongo log as I d/c and r/c between each the public and private IPs. I see the public ip connect all ok, but log is completely empty for the private ip attempt. I tried a few combos of the `mongoose.connect` including passing everything (inc authSource) as args, and passing a full url string. Same result for each

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: make sure you copy and paste the IP address correctly every time you use it

I had it mistyped in one of my configs